# ImagePicker is saying I don't have camera roll permissions, but I cannot find documentation about any of this

Tags: react-native, expo

I am making an upload screen in my app, I think I've got it most of the way but it is giving me a warning for missing camera roll permissions. I'd like some help with solving this problem.

I've looked for documentation online.

this is the document

```js
import { View, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Icon } from 'native-base';
import { ImagePicker } from 'expo';

var { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
class UploadTab extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="ios-add-circle" style={{ color: tintColor }} />
    ),
  };
  state = {
    image: null,
  };

  _handleChoosePhoto = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
    });
    console.log(result);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({ image: result.uri });
    }
    const options = {};
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
      console.log('response', response);
    });
  };
  render() {
    let { image } = this.state;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#1f1f1f',
          width: width,
          height: height,
        }}>
        <Button title="Choose Photo" onPress={this._handleChoosePhoto} />
        {image && (
          <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default UploadTab;
```

I need the button to open my camera roll so I can pick what I want to upload.

Warning(yellow)
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 6):
Error: Missing camera roll permission.
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#api

> Display the system UI for choosing an image or a video from the phone's library. Requires `Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL` on iOS only.

And in: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/#permissionsaskasynctypes

```
async function getLocationAsync() {
  const { Location, Permissions } = Expo;
  // permissions returns only for location permissions on iOS and under certain conditions, see Permissions.LOCATION
  const { status, permissions } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
  if (status === 'granted') {
    return Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({enableHighAccuracy: true});
  } else {
    throw new Error('Location permission not granted');
  }
}
```

swap out location with the permission that you need